# Does Exercise Decrease or Increase testosterone?

Tags: exercise

So when I exercise does it use up my testosterone, does it produce more? or none of the above. How do I use my testosterone storage and kinds of things can decrease it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seemingly simple question is actually rather complex.  I'm going to provide a list of articles to give you a good background on what it is you are asking, and then provide some highlights:

- [Anabolic Workouts Revisited](http://suppversity.blogspot.com/2012/09/anabolic-workouts-revisited.html) (anabolic means increase in testosterone, IGF-1, etc.)
- [Zoning in on the Big "T"](http://suppversity.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/intermittent-thoughts-on-building.html)
- [Quantifying the Big "T"](http://suppversity.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/intermittent-thoughts-on-building_02.html)

Some highlights that will help are:

- **Not all exercise is the same.**  Exercise that helps you become stronger will increase your T levels more than exercise that helps you endure longer.  I.e. weight training raises T levels more than marathon running.
- **Training density and volume affect T levels.**  You have a bigger response with full body training with short sets, short rest, and lots of volume.
- **There's more to building muscle than raising T levels.**  Testosterone is a hormone that triggers other hormones and physiological processes like IGF-1, etc.  You will have a natural rise in T levels while you sleep.
- **Stress and catabolic states can temporarily decrease T levels.**  Catabolism is a necessary process so you shouldn't try to eliminate it.  However, excessive catabolism due to overworking and under-recovering can depress T levels longer.  In short, you can do too much work over a short period of time.

Each of those articles has studies and further articles for you to look at and get a better picture.  Like most physiological processes, it is incredibly complex.